# Writing to BigQuery table using data from a Dataframe of a different structure with Spark Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-bigquery, apache-spark-sql, etl

I am building an ETL pipeline that reads from BQ performs a transformation and writes to another BQ table with a completely different table structure. The mapping isn't 1 to 1 and some fields are generated during the pipeline being run.

This is the schema of my existing dataframe which contains data (It is a join on two seperate BQ tables):

```
     |-- message_ID: string (nullable = false)
     |-- msg_priority: string (nullable = true)
     |-- subject: string (nullable = true)
     |-- sender: string (nullable = false)
     |-- jsonColumn: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- UserInfo: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- AccountName: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- AccountNumber: long (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- CorporateEmailAddress: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- FirstName: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- LastName: string (nullable = true)
     |-- REGION_NAME: string (nullable = true)
     |-- COUNTRY_CODE: string (nullable = true)
```

And the schema of my currently empty BQ table is:

```
     |-- email_id: string (nullable = false)
     |-- particpant: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- participant_type: string (nullable = false)
     |    |    |-- participant_email: string (nullable = false)  
     |-- priority: string (nullable = true)
     |-- subject: string (nullable = true)
```

Is there anyway using Spark to specify what I want to write into each column? Every example in documentation I am seeing is showing how to write the results into a matching table or to generate the table based on the Dataframe you are writing. However I am limited by having an existing table structure.

When testing out possible solutions I tried to select just 'subject' from table 1 and do a direct write into table 2 like so:

```
Dataset<Row> table1 = spark.sql(
                "SELECT subject FROM joinedTable"
        );

     
        table1.write().format("bigquery")
                .option("table", "outputTable")
                .option("writeMethod", "direct")
                .mode(SaveMode.Append)
                .save();
```

However this gave me the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryConnectorException$InvalidSchemaException: Destination table's schema is not compatible with dataframe's schema
```

So is this telling me that the Dataframe that I write to the table must match exactly? And if so how is it possible to achieve what I am doing?

Answer (score 1):

The DataFrame and the target table in BigQuery should have the same schema. As this is part of the application logic, both BigQuery and the spark-bigquery-connector cannot perform this schema translation. Here is a start:

```
Dataset<Row> table1 = spark.sql(
  "SELECT message_ID as email_id, ??? as participant, msg_priority as priority, subject FROM joinedTable"
);

table1.printSchema();
     
table1.write().format("bigquery")
  .option("table", "outputTable")
  .option("writeMethod", "direct")
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .save();
```

I have not created the participant, as I'm not sure how to convert the jsonColumn to an array of participants.

Notice the `printSchema()` call - please verify in the log that the schema of table1 is identical to the one in BigQuery.

Comment: Hi @david-rabinowitz I've followed your approach and have run into a similar issue. Maybe you would be able to provide more guidance here: [Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74151492/destination-tables-schema-is-not-compatible-with-dataframes-schema-during-sp)