# Destination table's schema is not compatible with dataframe's schema - During Spark Bigquery write

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-bigquery, apache-spark-sql

I have created a Dataframe to match the output table in Big Query that I want to write to using Spark.

The schema are like so:

Output Table:

```
 |-- email_id: string (nullable = false)
 |-- src_id: string (nullable = false)
 |-- src_name: string (nullable = false)
 |-- sent_local_time: string (nullable = false)
 |-- participant: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- participant_type: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- participant_email: string (nullable = false)
 |-- priority: string (nullable = true)
 |-- subject: string (nullable = true)
 |-- insertion_date: string (nullable = false)
 |-- run_date: string (nullable = false)
```

And my created Dataframe:

```
 |-- email_id: string (nullable = false)
 |-- src_id: string (nullable = false)
 |-- src_name: string (nullable = false)
 |-- sent_local_time: string (nullable = false)
 |-- participant: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- participant_type: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- participant_email: string (nullable = false)
 |-- priority: string (nullable = true)
 |-- subject: string (nullable = false)
 |-- insertion_date: string (nullable = false)
 |-- run_date: string (nullable = false)
```

The only difference visible is that the participant array 'element' doesn't contain null in my Dataframe and 'subject' is 'nullable=false'. However I'm not sure if that should make a difference.

I am attempting to write to output table using:

```
dataframe.write().format("bigquery")
                .option("table", "output-table")
                .option("writeMethod", "direct")
                .mode(SaveMode.Append)
                .save();
```

However this gives me the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryConnectorException$InvalidSchemaException: Destination table's schema is not compatible with dataframe's schema
```

Is there any other things I can check for why Spark wont allow me to write to the output table with my dataframe?

**EDIT:** I've now - by using a union - created a completely matching schema (nullable states of columns all match) and am still getting the same incompatible schema error as before so I'm stumped.

One thing I've noted is if I check the Big Query console, some columns appear as DATETIME rather than string. So I'm not sure why they are appearing as string when reading the table in spark. Maybe this is causing the mismatch?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Maybe you can add the 'google-cloud-dataproc' tag for getting some hints. The connector is developed by the dataproc team (according to Github at least).

Comment: You can use the flag `enableModeCheckForSchemaFields` to disable the comparison of nullable mode in both schema. But the comparison is all in all very strict, there is also an issue about that in [Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/issues/830)